# MariaDB/MySQL. Find row fields with max and min values in a grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I have this query. that returns the daily lowest and highest temperature:

```
select  year(DateTimeS),month(DateTimeS),day(DateTimeS),min(Low),max(High) from temperature
where year(DateTimeS) = 2018
group by year(DateTimeS),month(DateTimeS),day(DateTimeS)
```

I'm missing two fields in this query, LowTime and MaxTime. I can't figure out how to get the time where the min(low) and the max(High) happened. (DateTimeS is a DateTime Field, and the rest are decimal) The table has minute by minute temperature data like this:

```
+-----------------------+--------+-------+
|      "DateTimeS"      | "High" | "Low" |
+-----------------------+--------+-------+
| "2018-09-07 23:58:00" | "89"   | "87"  |
| "2018-09-07 23:57:00" | "88"   | "85"  |
| "2018-09-07 23:56:00" | "86"   | "82"  |
|        .              |        |       |
|        etc...         |        |       |
+-----------------------+--------+-------+
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: using MariaDB 10.3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MariaDB 10.3, you should be able to use window functions.  So:

```
select year(DateTimeS), month(DateTimeS), day(DateTimeS),
       min(Low), max(High),
       max(case when seqnum_l = 1 then DateTimeS end) as dateTimeS_at_low,
       max(case when seqnum_h = 1 then DateTimeS end) as dateTimeS_at_high
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date(DateTimeS) order by low) as seqnum_l,
             row_number() over (partition by date(DateTimeS) order by high desc) as seqnum_h
      from temperature t
     ) t
where year(DateTimeS) = 2018
group by year(DateTimeS), month(DateTimeS), day(DateTimeS);
```

Comment: Wow! like a boss!